# Is the class of DTI-groups closed under taking quotients?

Tags: gr.group-theory, finite-groups

Recall that a subgroup $H$ of a group $G$ is called a *TI-subgroup*
if for every $g \in G$ one has $H \cap H^g \in \{1,H\}$.
We say that a group $G$ is a DTI-group if the derived subgroups of all
of its subgroups are TI-subgroups of $G$.

*Question:* Is the class of DTI-groups closed under taking quotients?

Comment: An immediate observation is that the class of DTI-groups is closed under taking *subgroups*.

Comment: If $H$ is a subgroup of $G$, and $K$ is a subgroup of $H$, is your definition wanting $K'$ to be TI in $G$ or $H$?

Comment: @zibadawa timmy
$K'$ is TI in $G$. I.e. the derived subgroup of every subgroup of $G$ is a TI-subgroup of $G$.